# Find from a text if there is more than 6 consecutive number

Tags: sql, postgresql, text

I am trying to select from the following column `text` all those rows which have more than 6 consecutive numbers

```
  id                    text
   1         Hi how are you?
   2     my number 156784043
   3             Lucas Dresl
   4                34856708
   5         Collin Ave. 543 
   6                Mate man
   7      How much for this?
```

my expected result is just to have a select or count of how many rows fulfill the condition of 6 consecutive numbers or more

```
  id                    text
   2     my number 156784043
   4                34856708
```

or

```
 count_id
        2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `regexp`:

```
select count(*)
from yourtable
where yourfield regexp '[0-9]{6}'
```

---

Since you are using `postgresql` instead of `mysql`, use `~` instead:

```
select count(*)
from yourtable
where yourfield ~ '[0-9]{6}'
```

Comment: It is for 6 consecutive times **or more** . Does this regex handles the **more** scenario ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya  - Yes, this finds at least 6, so more would be just fine.

Comment: Just checking here: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s08.html

It says "{n}
 

n instances of preceding element"

Comment: Sorry, Regex is something which I am unable to understand. Please if you could clarify further!

Comment: yourfield must be the column name?

Comment: @LucasDresl I think column name is `text` as per OP's question description

Comment: @LucasDresl Yes, change `yourfield` with the name of the field in `yourtable` (change that one too).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It's similar to `like` -- it uses what's called `regular expressions` to do the lookup.  So in this case `[0-9]` represents any digit, and `{6}` represents at least how many there must be.

Comment: @sgeddes Thanks :)

Comment: and is postgresql would be regexp ?